# How to show Power BI report in MS dynamic NAV 2017?

Tags: azure, powerbi, navision

I want to show Power BI chart in navision 2017, for that I am following this link:

https://community.dynamics.com/nav/b/fajdigainfo/archive/2016/10/30/how-to-enable-microsoft-powerbi-in-nav-2017

My prob is, When i am trying to setup Azure active directory on portal.azure.com. It asks me for sign-on url and the url I am entering the value in this is what i got from navision 2017 setup azure active directory.

I am getting this from reply url in nav 2017 setup azure active directory:

http://mypcname:48900/DynamicsNAV100/WebClient/OAuthLanding.htm
If I am trying to open  this link  in my chrome, it shows nothing and says

This site can’t be reached

because my web client is working on 8080 port. so when I complete the whole process which includes granting the permission to azure app name, It shows the error that reply url doesn't match with http://mypcname:48900/DynamicsNAV100/WebClient/OAuthLanding.htm

I dont know from where 48900 is coming and why it's not working and says site can't be reached.

What i am missing?

Needs guidance,Thanks for your time.

Comment: I guess we cant do this without hosting the navision on azure as i am unable to access it from local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, we can access it from local machine also, see this link
http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/how-to-show-power-bi-report-in-MS-dynamic-nav-2017/m-p/93393#M39428